# How to implement query function?

Tags: kdb

1.table1:

```
([ID:`1`2`3]Name:`A`B`C;Client:`P`Q`S;ClientType:`QW`DS`WW;NameType:`jj`ll`oo;Basket:`QD`IO`LK;Sepal:5.1 4.5 23.5;Length:2 34 6;Species:`setosa`setosa`setosa)
```

2.write a simple function to select table1 data

```
api:{[Params]
   if [Params~();Params:()!()];
   defaultCols:`ID`Name`Client!(`ID`Name`Client);
if[`extraCols in key Params;
 defaultCols:defaultCols,Params[`extraCols]!Params `extraCols];
: ?[ select  from table1;();0b;defaultCols];
}
```

3.test `` api[(enlist[`extraCols]!enlist(`Species`Length))] ``

```
 ID Name  Client    Species  Length
 1    A     B        setosa    2
 2    B     Q        setosa    34
 3    C     S        setosa    6
```

When I used one Params to test:`` api[(enlist[`extraCols]!enlist(`Species))] ``
But result type error.In my limited experience with this . Could you please help me understand this . thanks.

And i want to get below result and how to change my api

```
ID Name  Client    Species
1    A     B       setosa
2    B     Q       setosa
3    C     S       setosa
```

Comment: Please format code, description properly. Also the image is missing

Comment: reformat code ...

Comment: If i need to change function api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the `type` error is coming from the statement in your `if` condition:

```
if[`extraCols in key Params;
 defaultCols:defaultCols,Params[`extraCols]!Params `extraCols]
```

You create a dictionary `` Params[`extraCols]!Params `extraCols ``

If there is only one element in `` Params`extraCols `` then you would need to enlist this when creating the dictionary to avoid such a type error, i.e:

`` enlist[Params`extraCols]!enlist Params`extraCols ``

It is also worthwhile putting a breakpoint inside your function to check the type of your arguments and give yourself an opportunity to debug. You should then be able to see that `` Params`extraCols `` is the *atom* `` `Species `` (should have type `-11h`) rather than a list.

Comment: Use api[(enlist[`Species]!enlist`Species)] still return defaultCols and no `Species col showing

Comment: You should update your `api` function as I have mentioned above, and call it with the same argument as before (```api[(enlist[`extraCols]!enlist(`Species))]```).